# How can I add a different image to the second scene in the XCode programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm not going to describe that I'm a noob in the Ios/Swift, it is clear from the query. So, I have an app, it has one ViewController and three scenes.  I've added a picture to the 1st scene with a TableView by the code, and it looks fine on all the devices. I want to add a different pic to the 2nd scene. I did: ImageView-Add pic-Content mode-Aspect Fill, but it is corrupted from device-to-device. The programmatically adding seems to be better.
The questions are: "Do I need to make a 2nd and 3rd views?" (I don't think it is a good idea) and if not "Where and how can I add a code to the ViewController?" (examples are appreciated)

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    let array = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.rowHeight = 70
        tableView.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "main1"))
    }
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the noobie solution on the noobie question. One need to create a CocoaPod and link it to the ViewController, then adding/formatting a code available.